# How to copy a line containing a string into the buffer within vim without moving the cursor?

Tags: vim

let's say I have a regex inside a line and I want to copy the first line above the cursor position that has that pattern without moving the cursor. For example (cursor being marked with ||):

```
This is a short example.  
On the other hand,  
I'm having trouble with it. ||
```

How to copy the sentence "This is a short example" to the position of the cursor (II)? If I search for the sentence, the cursor will be moved to This (?This is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
:?short?t.
```

It does a backward search for `short` (`?short`) and copies the matching line (`t`) to after the current line (`.`).

You can read about Ex commands in `:h :index` and about ranges in `:h range`.

***edit***

In reality, it doesn't exactly work like that but I think the explanation above may make a little more sense.

The exact mechanism is succinctly explained in `:h :copy`:

```
:[range]co[py] {address}
    Copy the lines given by [range] to below the line given by {address}.
```

Here, the `[range]` is the first line above the current one that matches `short` and the `{address}` is the current line, `.`.

I *love* Vim.

Comment: @romaini :) vim IS the best editor. ever.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways and plugins that come to my mind, but the natural way would be to just search (`?This is`), yank, and then jump back to the original position with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and paste. With the help of the jump list (cp. `:help jumplist`), the temporary move isn't so bad.